# d3 scaling for responsive design

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

Is there a way of controlling the scaling for d3.js charts? The width and height of the svg is to to be the same as the viewBox width/height?

```
var svgroot = d3.select($(el)[0])
      .append("svg")
      .attr("viewBox", "0 0 " + width + " " + height)
      .attr("width", width)
      .attr("height", height)
      .attr("preserveAspectRatio", "xMidYMid meet");
```

Comment: This article has some really good examples of listening to window resize events: https://www.safaribooksonline.com/blog/2014/02/17/building-responsible-visualizations-d3-js/

Comment: I've been following this page - but this not such a simple chart. It has defs, and masking properties.